# Best way to show large dataset using WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to show large data on WPF DataGrid, but the performance are not good and when I do stress test, it crash.

I have an API and it will constantly send me data. (max 3 million,200 message per second)

structure like below. (simplified version)

```
    public class BaseData{
        public string orderID {get;set;}
        public string side {get;set;}
        public string time {get;set;}
        public BaseData(ref string msg)
        {
            orderID = msg.Substring(...);            
            side = msg.Substring(...);            
            time = msg.Substring(...);            
        }
    }
```

I want to show all of the data on DataGrid, so I create a DataGrid like below.

```
<DataGrid Margin="10" Name="OrderDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="OrderID" Binding="{Binding orderID}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Side" Binding="{Binding side}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding time}" />
    </DataGird.Columns>

...... style stuff ......

</DataGrid>
```

In MainWindow(), I assign an ObservableCollection to ItemsSource.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    ...... load config ......


    OrderDataGrid.ItemsSource = APIThread.orderDataCollection;
}
```

API runs in another thread. API callback insert data to orderDataCollection.
use BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization to prevent crash.

```
public class APIThread
{
    public static ObservableCollection<BaseData> orderDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<BaseData>();
    private static object orderDataLock = new object();
    private static Thread recvThread = null;
    public static isStop = false;

    public APIThread()
    {
        // prevent race condition?, but still crashes.
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(APIThread.orderDataCollection, orderDataLock);
    }

    public static void processRecv(string msg)
    {
        ...... do something ......
        orderDataCollection.add(BaseData(ref msg));
    }

    private static runAPI()
    {
        TheAPI theAPI = new TheAPI();
        theAPI.OnRecv += processRecv;
        theAPI.start();

        while(1){
            if (isStop) break;
            ...... do something ......
            sleep(1000);
        }
        ...... disconnect API ......

    }

    public void start()
    {
        if(recvThread == null || recvThread.IsAlive == false)
        {
         recvThread = new Thread(() => runAPI());
         recvThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the actual program, after few minutes, the DataGrid start to slow down (it can't update 200 rows per second any more.)

After about 200,000 rows, it crashed and show:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' 
...... some error here, but not in English, it says COM Object was disconnect or busy. ......
```

Is there any better approach to show large dataset??

Comment: You can use the pagination method and virtualize your data. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1257860/Paging-WPF-DataGrid

Comment: There is no reason to display more data than the user can see on the screen, i.e. you shouldn't add 200,000 rows at once.